# mysql_query not fulfilling all specified parameters

Tags: php, mysql

so here is my code and I will tell you the problem after that:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
    setInterval( function() {
    $('#responsechat<?php echo $otherchatuser ?>').load('echogetconversation.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>&otherchatuser=<?php echo $otherchatuser; ?>&numberofmessages=<?php echo $numberofmessages; ?>');
    <?php
    $subtractlogintime8 = time() - 600;
    $data8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loggedin WHERE username='$otherchatuser' and time > '$subtractlogintime'");
    $numrows8 = mysql_num_rows($data8);
    ?>
    if (<?php echo $numrows8; ?> == 1 )
    {
    document.getElementById("checkloggedin<?php echo $otherchatuser; ?>").innerHTML = '<img src="loggedin.png">';
    document.getElementById("checkloggedin<?php echo $otherchatuser; ?>").style.marginLeft = '5px';
    }
    else
    {
    document.getElementById("checkloggedin<?php echo $otherchatuser; ?>").innerHTML = '';
    }
    }, 4000);
    </script>
```

This is my code, which gets users who are logged in and also does other things.  The problem that I am having occurs on this line:

```
 $data8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loggedin WHERE username='$otherchatuser' and time > '$subtractlogintime'");
```

The query successfully gets users from the database, but seems to be ignoring the "and time > '$subtractlogintime'");" part of the query.  I have no idea why this is occurring and anyone who could possibly tell me what I have forgotten would be extremely appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: This calls for step-by-step debugging. What does `$subtractlogintime` actually contain?

Comment: Well, this is what I set the variable as $subtractlogintime8 = time() - 600;.  So it is the current time minus ten minutes.

Comment: When you echo the query for debugging purposes, what does it look like? What type of field is `time`?

Comment: @Eggo you are using `$subtractlogintime8` when assigning and `$subtractlogintime` in the query

Comment: omg thanks Pekka you just solved it!

Comment: What datatype is your time column?

Comment: That is what happens when you copy and paste code form a different page.  I just forgot to change that.  If this has been solved should I post a new Answer saying that it has been?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIME is a reserved keyword in MySQL because of the TIME datatype. If it's not crashing, you would probably better off backticking your "TIME" keyword to refer to the field `time`.

```
$data8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loggedin WHERE username='$otherchatuser' and `time` > '$subtractlogintime'");
```

Also note that, this code COULD be prone to SQL injection but we can't be sure without seeing the full code...

Comment: Hmm, that still does not fix the problem.  What is still happening is that it is getting all users from the database but ignoring `time` > '$subtractlogintime'

Comment: MySQL permits some keywords to be used as unquoted identifiers because many people previously used them. Examples are those in the following list: 

•
ACTION

 •
BIT

 •
DATE

 •
ENUM

 •
NO

 •
TEXT

 •
TIME

 •
TIMESTAMP

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Pekka solved it; i was using the wrong variable.